# Ace editor - how to include help text and snippet in same popup

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

In ace editor; Is there a way to include help text in the autocomplete popup along with snippet?
Preferably without having to maintain two separate files/data structures.

Comment: can you provide code please?

Comment: I'm currently looking at the build/ autocomplete demo code - https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need to modify https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.0/lib/ace/ext/language_tools.js#L76 to return snippet description instead of content